# How can I run Fugitive's :Ggrep in a new split?

Tags: vim, vim-fugitive

I want to use Tim Pope's Vim plugin [Fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive)'s `:Ggrep [regex]` command to search my codebase, but I would like to open the first match in a new split. How can I do this?

Comment: Will `:split|Ggrep foo` work? or how about doing `<c-w>s` before the grep?

Comment: That doesn't work because Fugitive uses the current buffer's file to determine which git repo it's in. If I open a new split, it has no git repo to reference.

Comment: `:split` w/o any arguments or `<c-w>s` will split the current buffer yielding two windows w/ the same buffer. Therefore `:Ggrep` will work as intended. I have tested both methods out on a repo of mine and it works w/o issue

Comment: Doh! You're right. I was thinking `:new` not split. If you write this as an answer, I'll make it as solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split before you `Ggrep`! Either use `:split` or `<c-w>s` and then grep (`:grep`/`:vimgrep`/`:Ggrep`/`:Ack`/etc).

#### Usage

```
:sp|Ggrep foo
```

and/or

```
<c-w>s:Ggrep foo
```

#### Using the `quickfix` list

Grep command typically update the `quickfix` list so it is often handy to have good mappings to `:cnext` and `:cprev`. I use `]q` and `[q` respectively which are provided by Tim Pope's [unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) plugin, along with many other helpful mappings. `:copen` will open `quickfix` window if you need to look at the results as a whole.

#### For more information see:

```
:h :sp
:h ctrl-w_s
:h :Ggrep
:h quickfix
:h :cnext
:h :cope
```